# Openerp - Show discount calculated from price list in quotation/invoice report

Tags: odoo

Is there a way to show discounts calculated from pricelist in the quotation and invoice reports ?

I know there is a module to give a discount manually on an order line, but i can't find a way to show discounts from pricelist.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

By using product_visible_discount, you just have to add another pricelist with a negatif value. And check the visible_discount option on that pricelist.